# Polynomial rings in infinitely indeterminants

Tags: abstract-algebra

How can we prove that (the set of all polynomials in infinitely non commutative indeterminants over $k$) is a ring, where $k$ is a ring with unity?

Adding two polynomials is a polynomial, but for commutativity 
How can we show the following:
$ax_1+bx_2=bx_2+ax_1$ (commutativity of addition)
If we have finite number of variable it is easy to prove it, (we take the $n-1$ variables...), but what about the infinite number of variables? 
Can someone give me a hint?

Comment: You're saying that you **don't** want the indeterminates to commute multiplicatively? So, for example, you want $x_1x_2\neq x_2x_1$ with $x_1,x_2$ indeterminate? As for commutativity of addition, it should be clear if you look at the explicit definition of the set, and the definition of the addition operation on the set.

Comment: If I have x1 & x2 , then I can consider x1  as a constant to the respect to x2 , so ax1 is a constant

Comment: Note that even if you have infinitely many indeterminates, the number of indeterminates in any specific polynomial is finite.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way I imagine such a creature might be explicitly defined. Given any nonnegative integer $n$, define $\textbf{n}:=\{j\in\Bbb Z\mid0\leq j,j<n\}$, so for example, $\textbf{0}=\emptyset,$ $\textbf{1}=\{0\}$, $\textbf{2}=\{0,1\}$, and so on.

Your set of indeterminates, let's call $X$. Since your indeterminates don't commute, then your monomials would be finite strings of elements of $X$--or equivalently, functions $\textbf{n}\to X$ for some nonnegative integer $n$--and your multiplication will just be concatenation. That is, the set of all your monomials will be $$M(X):=\{p:\textbf{n}\to X\mid n\text{ a nonnegative integer}\},$$ and we define the operation $*$ on $M(X)$ as follows: given $p_1,p_2\in M(X)$, say with $p_1:\textbf{m}\to X$ and $p_2:\textbf{n}\to X$, we define $p_1*p_2$ by $$(p_1*p_2)(j)=\begin{cases}p_1(j) & 0\leq k<m\\p_2(j-m) & m\leq j<n.\end{cases}$$ You can check that $*$ is an associative, non-commutative operation on $M(X)$, which is cancellative and has the empty function (the unique function $\textbf{0}\to X$) as identity.

Now, polynomials in elements of $X$ with coefficients in $k$ will be finite collections of monomials in $M(X)$ with a non-zero element of $k$ associated with each--that is, they will be functions $f:M(X)\to k$ such that $f(p)=0_k$ for all but finitely-many $p\in M(X)$--so we'll define the set of all such polynomials to be $$k[X]:=\bigl\{f:M(X)\to k\mid f(p)=0_k\text{ for all but finitely-many }p\in M(X)\bigr\}.$$ We need $k[X]$ to be a commutative group under some addition operation $\oplus$, and we need some multiplication operation $\odot$ on $k$ that is associative, left- and right-distributive over $\oplus$. Addition is readily defined by $$(f_1\oplus f_2)(p)=f_1(p)+f_2(p)$$ for all $p\in M(X)$, where $+$ is the addition operation of $k$. Multiplication is a bit trickier, but after some consideration, we find that we need $$(f_1\odot f_2)(p)=\sum\bigl\{f_1(p_1)\cdot f_2(p_2)\mid p_1,p_2\in M(X)\text{ such that }p_1*p_2=p\bigr\},$$ where $\cdot$ is the multiplication operation of $k$.

---

Those should all work out as we want them to, but there are a great many tedious details to verify, and of course you may be using notation and definitions that look nothing like what I've done above.

If you are using other definitions for $k[X]$ and its operations, you might want to specify those, so we can better assist you.

Comment: In other words, $M$ is the free monoid on $X$, and $k[X]$ is the monoid algebra over $M$. All these constructions are well-known and included in every good book on algebra. The calculations for these two separate constructions are not tedious.

Comment: @Martin: I wondered if those structures had some canonical name. I developed them on my own a few days ago, because I didn't like the purely formal definition that I've encountered elsewhere. I deemed it unlikely that I was the first person ever to define them that way. Good to know I was right. (BTW, to my mind, *all* calculations are tedious. ;-) )

Comment: In fact, adjoint functor theorems produce all these left adjoints for algebraic categories for *free*.